# str_pad with non english characters

Tags: php, unicode-string

When I try to str_pad() with zero on a hebrew word, it doesn't add the required amount of zeros.

For example:

```
$word='שלום';
$str=str_pad($word,10,' ',STR_PAD_RIGHT);
```

The result:

```
שלום00
```

Comment: Those are multibyte characters taking more space than you think they do

Comment: You can't reliably use single-byte functions on multi-byte strings. Possible duplicate of [PHP, str\_pad unicode issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773072/php-str-pad-unicode-issue)

Answer (score 4):

`str_pad(...)` is not multibyte safe. This means that, since you're using 4 2-byte characters, that functions sees that the string length is 8, therefore only 2 zeros will be used for padding.

I've spotted this user-contributed function inside the PHP manual. It's untested and use at your own risk, but it seems to me that's what you're looking for.

```
function mb_str_pad ($input, $pad_length, $pad_string, $pad_style, $encoding="UTF-8") {
   return str_pad($input, 
                  strlen($input)-mb_strlen($input,$encoding)+$pad_length, 
                  $pad_string, $pad_style); 
}
```

Comment: THANK GOD THIS ANSWER EXISTS, THANK YOU FOR YOUR EXISTANCE, YOU HELPED ME SO MUCH!