# En dash and PHP

Tags: php, strlen

PHP is calculating En dash/Em dash (`–`) length as `3`. I tried it with different PHP versions (5.x, 7.x, 8.0), but the result is the same in all the versions.

Is it expected or a known bug? It doesn't happen in other languages (ie. Javascript, Python).

Are there any more such characters? How do we handle this?

Comment: With what code do you get this result?

Comment: Use `mb_strlen()`.

Comment: `strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.`. That dash must be 3 bytes long.

Comment: Oh okay. Got it. There is no `multibyte` function for `str_pad` though.

Answer (score 0):

The en dash / em dash takes, UTF-8 encoded, 3 bytes. Check with [`mb_strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php). [`strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) counts the number of bytes in a string.

See documentation:

> Note: strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How about `str_pad`? Should I go with a custom solution for that?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773072/php-str-pad-unicode-issue.