# Laravel 'Str' helper class doesn't work with Unicode

Tags: php, laravel, unicode, helper

Since I'm new to laravel, I'm trying codes from the documentation. I got to the helper classes.

When in my controller I wrote the code bellow,

```
        $a='გიორგი გოგიავა';
        $b="George Gogiava";
        echo Str::length($a), '</br>';
        echo Str::padLeft($b,  20, '*'), '</br>';
        echo Str::of($a)->padLeft(40, '*');
```

I got the following answer:

******George Gogiava
გიორგი გოგიავა
14

Firstly, I'm surprised that he printed the length at the end, and secondly, as you can see, the function does not work with Unicode.

I am waiting for an explanation about this and how to solve it?

Comment: Is `$a` not 14 characters long? Also the 14 being at the end indicates that at some point things switched to Right-to-left

Comment: @apokryfos:   Right-to-left?  I don't think so. padLeft doesn't work.

Comment: it looks like it worked to me. there's stars on the left of $b

Comment: @apokryfos but not on the left side of $a

Comment: Where does it say it works with Unicode? They are just accessing the old PHP functions [on the backend](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Str.php#L466).

Comment: Yes it seems that `str_pad` doesn't work with unicode . There's [an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14773775/487813) you can implement yourself

Comment: use Str;  in top of controller