# Formatting output in PHP (not HTML marup)

Tags: php, text-formatting

please help me with the following problem:

I need to output some data in a style like multiplication table. It is not a web page so html markup is not possible. Mainly, I need to know how to make an output right-aligned and put in front of it the same "space".

example of output:

```
 1    12    80
20     2     3
 4    25    12
```

I tried to experiment with printf. However, I did not find any reasonable solution.

Thank You for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to output a simple ascii table in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082211/how-to-output-a-simple-ascii-table-in-php)

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem.